# Why does my UITableViewController not refresh when I use UIRefreshControl?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableViewController that implements the UIRefreshControl to refresh the data from the server, from the debugs I can see that the refresh method is called and the new correct data is downloaded but my UITableViewController is not reflecting this.

if I close the UITableViewController and open it again the correct data is shown

my refresh code looks like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];

    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(updateData)

    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.refreshControl = refresh;
}

- (void) updateData {

    [ShopifyWebServices fetchAllProductsInCollection:shopifyCollectionTitle];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stopRefresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

- (void)stopRefresh {

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

}
```

Comment: to manage data of tableview, you should use reloadData function of table view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are responsible for reloading your table view once you have the new data. The refresh control doesn't do anything other than tell you it's been triggered.

I'd expect some sort of delegate method or completion block after `fetchAllProductsInCollection`, and that is where you should be calling `endRefreshing` and reloading your table data.

Comment: I tried this but it still won't refresh unless I go out and back in - (void) updateData {
    
    [ShopifyWebServices fetchAllProductsInCollection:shopifyCollectionTitle];
    
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopRefresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Is it possible I have missed to connect a datasource or something?

Comment: That code will reload the data immediately. If you put `[self.tableView reloadData];` in your `stopRefresh` method it might work, but you're still just waiting for 5 seconds instead of actually doing it when the fetch has finished. If you hadn't connected the datasource then it would never work.

Comment: This worked, and i implemented a notification from the async call so I am refreshing when its done,

Comment: You're not really showing enough code - it sounds like you're not doing anything with the data that comes back from this fetch, but something else knows about it, and that something gives it to the table view when you close and re-open it. Where does the table's data come from? How are you passing it in? There must be some sort of notification or delegate of `ShopifyWebServices` that you can use.

Comment: sorry it is working as you stated, I made a silly comment mistake when I moved code around